# PHP FPDF Label outputting gibberish/garbage data if not enough labels are printed, but with enough it works just fine

Tags: php, pdf, label, fpdf

I have a label generator that works fine if you have enough labels to print, in my case it's roughly 3 pages worth of 5160's, or ~70 individual entries. If you have less than that number you end up looking at this instead of downloading your PDF:
[image]

If you have enough entries it will however work properly and look like this:
[image]

Noteworthy is that when I changed from real data to dummy data so I could take a screen cap of it the number of pages needed to be ~6, so it seems to fail when there is not enough raw text, rather than individual entries.

I haven't got a clue how to debug this. This is my code that I am working with:

```
$pdf = new PDF_Label('5160');

        $pdf->AddPage();

        foreach ($entries as $entry) {
            $name = 'Demo thing';

            $date = Carbon::create($order->{'Delivery Date'})->format('M d, Y');

            $text = sprintf("%s\n%s, %s, %s\n%s\n%s", 'Business', 'Employee', '4A', 'Floor 7' ?? '---', $date, $name);
            $pdf->Add_Label($text);
        }

        $pdf->Output();
```

Has anyone encountered this while working with FPDF_Label before? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: More info about the error checking that FPDF does:

```
protected function _checkoutput()
{
    if(PHP_SAPI!='cli')
    {
        if(headers_sent($file,$line))
            $this->Error("Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at $file:$line)");
    }
    if(ob_get_length())
    {
        var_dump('test');
        // The output buffer is not empty
        if(preg_match('/^(\xEF\xBB\xBF)?\s*$/',ob_get_contents()))
        {
            // It contains only a UTF-8 BOM and/or whitespace, let's clean it
            ob_clean();
        }
        else
            $this->Error("Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file");
    }
}

//below is within the main output function
            $this->_checkoutput();
            
            if(PHP_SAPI!='cli')
            {
                // We send to a browser
                header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
                header('Content-Disposition: inline; '.$this->_httpencode('filename',$name,$isUTF8));
                header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
            }
            echo $this->buffer;
            break;
```

When I see my error it goes through this bit of code and does not output any of those errors you see, so we can say that there is no headers already sent or output in the buffer.

Comment: I think that error happens when you accidently output a warning/error message in the pdf stream. Did you check your logs to see if there are warning/errors? You might also want to try disabling errors/warnings at the start of your PHP script.

Comment: @bassxzero There is a $this->_checkoutput(); call that happens before it outputs the headers and content. This checks for anything that has already been output with if(ob_get_length()), and I have checked to make sure that is not triggered when this problems happens, so I don't believe that's the cause.

Comment: @bassxzero I added that code I just mentioned to the main post too

Comment: Are you sure you have an output buffer started at the start of the script/request?

Comment: @bassxzero I believe FPDF handles that automatically. I just took the demo code from http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script29.php and plugged it into my function that serves the PDF. It does not work with the given 20 entries, it does work if I bump it up to 200. My function does nothing except require the files, and then do the sample code linked on that page. I then took the sample code and moved it outside of the laravel site where I am normally working, it works there with 20 or 200 just fine. So my problem is hidden somewhere in Laravel. Oh geeze.

Comment: I don't see `ob_start` in the FPDF class.

Comment: @bassxzero I made an answer post with a solution for this, something in Laravel was changing the headers if the content was too short, so I call exit; immediately after '$pdf->Output();'. Not an ideal fix but I think finding the root cause is beyond my abilities if it's within Laravel.

Comment: The "gibberish" is the raw (uninterpreted) PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this, though it doesn't address the underlying problem. I was comparing headers in the network tab for the working and not working scenarios and noticed that 'Content-Type: application/pdf' was dropped for the shorter entry set (plus some other changes). Since this did not happen outside my Laravel site I tried adding 'exit;' the line after '$pdf->Output();' and it now works regardless of how many entries.

With the longer entry sheet I noticed it adds 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' as well as keeping the 'Content-Type: application/pdf'. Perhaps there is a bug in the Laravel header handling related to that? I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the following

```
ob_clean(); before $pdf = new PDF_Label('5160');
```

and

```
ob_flush();
exit;
```

after

```
$pdf->Output();
```